# Alternate img src... possible without JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, html, progressive-enhancement

I'm using `jQuery.load` to load in some content but for SEO and for JavaScript-disabled browsers I've used Progressive Enhancement to normal link to the content using `<a>` tags and when JavaScript is in to load the content.

My problem is that on one of the pages/loaded content there is an image if the content is loaded using JavaScript the image source would be `src="images/picture.png"` but if its loaded using the `<a>` tags it would be `src="../images/picture.png"` (note the `../`). I know I could fix this by change the file structure by having the loaded pages in the same folder level as the file but this would mean I'd have a load of files in my root / or a main file hidden, giving me a messy URL for that page.

I was wondering if I could specify alternative sources for an images (of course I can not use JavaScript to do this; it must be pure HTML).

RIGHT ... DONT THINK I MADE THAT VERY CLEAR AT ALL ..

What I need to change is:

- if that page is clicked through the `<a>` link the image source should be `src="../images/picture.jpg"`
- if the content is loaded using `jQuery.load` the image source should be `src="images/picture.jpg"`

This cannot be achieved using JavaScript as it's for when JS isn't working or is disabled.

Comment: Methinks you meant JavaScript, not Java. :-)

Comment: Why not use absolute paths (such as `/images/picture.png`) everywhere so that you don't have to care what the browser thinks the current directory is?

Comment: Are you aware that jQuery *is* JavaScript?

Comment: OH -- I think I understand, the page is located in a sub-directory -- when jQuery loads it, the main page is not in the sub-directory so you want one path, but when you click on the link the images won't work if you change the paths for where it will be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you do.  Write the page to work when it is clicked on via the A tag.

Then via jQuery if you load it via jQuery, change all the paths to what you want.

It is a lot of work.  Much simpler, just use absolute paths.

Side note:  This question has nothing to do with progressive enhancement.